# libwinpthread-1.dll, libgcc_s_seh-1.dll y error 0xc000007b

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Utilizo el IDE CLion para programar en C++, y llevo muy poco tiempo. Estoy haciendo un minijuego en consola donde necesito generar números aleatorios.
Use rand() con la libreria estandar y time(), pero el entorno me recomienda utilizar un generador diferente, siguiendo con las "convenciones" de C++11, y he decidido utilizar la biblioteca random de esta forma:

```
#include < random >

std::random_device rd;  
std::mt19937 mt(rd());  
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(4, 77);  

roca.mover(dist(mt));
```

Cuando ejecuto el juego en la consola del entorno, funciona más o menos bien.

El problema viene cuando quiero ejecutar mi juego.exe por fuera, pues primero me dice que me falta "libgcc_s_seh-1.dll". Lo instalo y me pide "libwinpthread-1.dll". Y cuando ambos están instalados *en el directorio del ejecutable* (no se si se hace así) me dice que no se puede iniciar la aplicación porque ha ocurrido este error -> 0xc000007b.

Puedo usar `rand()` de la manera tradicional, pero ya que estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje me gustaría saber por qué ocurre este error, cómo solucionarlo...

Uso Windows 10 64 bits y mi compilador es MinGW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esas librerias que te faltan son dependencias del compilador.

Estas librerías se encontrarán en la carpeta *libs* del compilador. Necesitas copiarlas junto al ejecutable para que funcione en otros equipos.

Si el ejecutable aun asi no arranca el problema es que faltan mas dependencias.

Prueba a enlazar con

```
-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

Porque estas dos dependencias tambien suelen ser necesarias con gcc / mingwin.

También puedes utilizar la herramienta [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) para examinar el ejecutable y averiguar qué dependencias te faltan.